# PL/pgSQL function pass dynamically created where string to select query

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I stuck on creating my pl/pgsql function.

I've got something like that

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(var text[][])
    RETURNS VARCHAR AS
    $BODY$
    DECLARE 
        _value VARCHAR;
        _tmp text;
    BEGIN
        _tmp  := '';
        FOR i IN 1 .. array_upper(var,1) LOOP
    _tmp := _tmp  || ' ' || var[i][1] ||  ' IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ' || var[i][2] || ' AND';
        END LOOP;

        EXECUTE 'SELECT value FROM table where $1 1=1'
        INTO _value
        USING _tmp;

RETURN _value;
END;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

And then I do

```
SELECT test(ARRAY[['col1', '1'], ['col2','2']])
```

I simply want to add string to my query and run it as condition. But I get syntax error "where should be boolean" or  "syntax error at or near "1""

Is something like that even possible?

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `USING` to construct your [dynamic query](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) (it's for the query's individual parameters). Use concatenation (`||`) or `format()` for that. (Also: always take care for sql injection when using dynamic queries.)

Comment: ahhh concatenation works great here! Thanks. Sql injections - good point.

Answer (score -1):

Initialize `_tmp` with the first entry of the array, then add any further entries.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(var text[][]) RETURNS varchar AS $BODY$
DECLARE 
    _value varchar;
    _tmp   text;
BEGIN
    _tmp  := var[1][1] ||  ' IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ' || var[1][2];
    FOR i IN 2 .. array_upper(var,1) LOOP
      _tmp := _tmp  || ' AND ' || var[i][1] ||  ' IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ' || var[i][2];
    END LOOP;

    EXECUTE 'SELECT value FROM table WHERE ' || _tmp;
    INTO _value;

    RETURN _value;
END; $BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE STRICT;
```